# tmux - What does bind-key -r mean?

Tags: tmux

When I am running in tmux and use 
C-b ?, I can get a list of all the commands.

However, I observe that some commands are bind-key, followed by the command, and others are bind-key -r, followed by the command.

I did quite a bit of searching, but couldn't find documentation that explained the difference.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Quoting the [TMUX(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux) manpage:

> The -r flag indicates this key may repeat, see the repeat-time option.

And a quick search for `repeat-time` yields this:

> **repeat-time time**
>        Allow multiple commands to be entered without pressing the prefix-key again in the specified time milliseconds (the default is 500).  Whether a key repeats may be set when it is bound using
>        the -r flag to bind-key.  Repeat is enabled for the default keys bound to the resize-pane command.